# How to limit search and replace string in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using this to search and replace strings in mySQL:

```
UPDATE products 
   SET prodname = REPLACE(prodname, " S", "'S")
```

The products contain strings such as "TYLENOL TABS 100 S" which I'd like to convert to "TYLENOL TABS 100'S".

However, using the above SQL statement also affects strings such as "NIKE SHOES", which will become "NIKE'SHOES" -- which I obviously don't like.

Is there a way I can limit the replace function (or is there another way to do this) so I can get the result I want? The " S" is usually at the tail end of the string for most of my data, which I'm hoping will be helpful.

Comment: does the ' s' always follow a number?

Answer (score 6):

You could limit that to a subset more closed to your needs by putting a WHERE clause with a REGEXP():

```
UPDATE products SET prodname = REPLACE(prodname, " S", "'S") WHERE prodname REGEXP '[0-9]\sS'
```

This matches the rows that product names that have a number, followed by a space, followed by an S. Sadly there is no REGEX replace implemented by default in MySQL, to be able to replace only that match, so this will also replace "TYLENOL TAB SOLO 100 S" to "TYLENOL TAB'SOLO 100'S", but it won't replace in your original "TYLENOL TABS 100 S"

Comment: I'm not so sure that your answer solves the problem since you said there is no regex replace by default?

Comment: Indeed, there is no REGEXP replace, but it updates **only** the records that have values in the form of 'number space S'

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
UPDATE products SET prodname = REPLACE(prodname, " S", "'S")
WHERE prodname LIKE "% S"
```

This means products with a `prodname` ending with S will be updated. The `%` char means anything.

Comment: this will still replace too much when the where criteria is met, as would be the case with `tylenol something 100 S`  you would end up with `tylenol'something 100'S`

Comment: @andyuyboco You're welcome! @Nathan gonzalez is however correct, watch out for `prodname` like `TYLENOL S-WORDS 100 S`.

Comment: Yes, I found that out the hard way. But anyway, I'm having a jolly time fixing it.

Comment: this works just like before :) - it replaces "TYLENOL S-WORDS" also

Comment: @andyuyboco Revert "TYLENOL S-WORDS" with `UPDATE products SET prodname = REPLACE(prodname, "'S", " S")
WHERE prodname LIKE "%'S_%"`

Answer (score 1):

If you only want `prodname` ending in `S`, then you could also use:

```
UPDATE products SET prodname = CONCAT(SUBSTR(prodname,1,CHAR_LENGTH(prodname)-2),"'S")
WHERE prodname LIKE "% S"
```

This wouldn't replace `TYLENOL SOMETHING 100 S` to `TYLENOL 'SOMETHING 100'S` but to `TYLENOL SOMETHING 100'S`. The `%` char means anything, as the other answers at the moment.

Comment: Sadly, this came too late. :p
I'll keep it in mind the next time I need it though.

Comment: what if the product name is 'TYLENOL SOMETHING 100 S BEST EVER'?

Comment: @Tudor You're right, but I started my answer with this. The reason why I gave this answer was because I read: `The " S" is usually at the tail end of the string for most of my data, which I'm hoping will be helpful.`