# mysql replace string count limit

Tags: mysql, string, csv, replace

Mysql Replace function replace the string wherever it found in the specified column or string, is there any other method which can limit the replaces count on a column/string ?

```
# replace 32 from the string, there are 3 occurance
SELECT REPLACE('32,138,149,145,146,121,134,127,129,120,132,232','32','');

# note: 132,232 converted to 1 and 2
print>>> ,138,149,145,146,121,134,127,129,120,1,2
```

How to overcome this?

Comment: do you want to replace exact 32 by empty string only and not replace the strings like 132 and 232 ?

Comment: if you want to replace exact '32' and no other combinations like 132 and 232 etc, this may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093813/how-to-limit-search-and-replace-string-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks, but I have seen that post its not what I am searching for. I only want to limit 1 replace in the string. Thanks to @Nedret Recep Solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fictively concatenate the haystack with ',' and then look for the needle ',32,' and replace it with ','

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT(',','32,138,149,145,146,121,134,127,129,120,132,232',','), ',32,', ',');
```

Additionally, if you like, you would also trim commas on both ends.

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',','32,138,149,145,146,121,134,127,129,120,132,232',','), ',32,', ','));
```

Comment: Please note that srting operations are slow in general. I suppose these are ID lists and you have some non-normal DB structure if you need to use lists of IDs a strings. I would recommend you to normalize the DB structure and use joins.

Comment: when 5000+ more records will be for each 250 branches then rows will move to 5000x250 rows that may exceed 1250000+, InnoDB gives advantage of row locking while updating therefore considering its better to go only on 5000 rows as compare to 1250000+ rows.

Thanks for best solution i can have :)